# Firefox doesn't Copy background color of a table

Tags: html, css, firefox

When I copy/paste a table with background colors in the .css file into excel Firefox doesn't copy the background. However if the style is directly defined in the table itself it is copied.

IE & Chrome preserve the formatting.

A JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZCVC9/

For reference the code:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Not working table</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
    </tr>
</table>

<table style="background-color: #faa835;">
    <tr>
        <th>working table</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And the .css:

```
.table {
    background-color: #faa835;
}
```

Is this intended? Is this a bug in Firefox? I tried also the Dafizilla Table2Clipboard Addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dafizilla-table2clipboard/ there it works.

Firefox tested: 25 & 27.0.1

Comment: I tested in 27.0.1, but its working well.

Comment: Interesting. Doesn't really seem like a "bug" though... more like something overlooked.

Comment: Reproduced in Firefox 27.0.1 and Excel 2003

Comment: Have you tried using `bgcolor="#faa835"`?

Answer (score 2):

When we code a web page, we traditionally use the external (style.css) CSS, or internal CSS above our content in `<head><link href="style.css" /></head>`. But when HTML viewed in **document/Excel** WYSIWYG(What you see is what you get) as you mentioned or browser-based **email apps** (like YahooMail!, Gmail, Hotmail, etc), those applications **strip out** the `<head><link href="style.css" /></head>` Head and BODY tags by default.

So we should code **inline** to our content so any background colors or BODY settings should be handled inline.

So Answer to you question is it's not about browser support!, Developing web and email template or inserting it in document WYSIWYG is different. WYSIWYG case you should use inline style. `<table style="background:#f00"><tr><td>Working Example</td></tr></table>`

Comment: I'm aware of this. But Chrome & IE apply the styles before stripping it out. And as long as we have Paste as Plain & Paste as HTML this is fine. Beside this (IMHO) putting CSS inline should never be an answer to a formatting problem.

Comment: @christian this is the way how browsers also work.. some browser engine copy css to inline and show and some like FF (gecko) don't copy external css here is an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/HarishBoke/uUzkn/ 

Explanation:
I have copied it from browser and you can see how browsers treat your code, Use Inline is depends whether you are coding for web or WYSIWYG/email template but for WYSIWYG you must inline as browser do  the same.